# Правильно ли выражение "Сбор гостей"?

Tags: стилистика

Добрый день!
Правильно ли в программе, приглашениях писать "Сбор гостей "? Или стилистически лучше выражение "прибытие гостей"? Или оба варианты не точны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Сбор" может ассоциироваться с местом, где люди стоя мучительно дожидаются друг друга, чтобы вместе поехать куда-то. Поэтому в приглашении лучше так написать: "Ждём вас к... часам". Более формально (пункт программы мероприятия): "Начало встречи (прибытие гостей)....... в таком-то часу".